# How to add spaces between bars in recharts vertical bar chart?

Tags: recharts

I have this code

```
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";
import {
  LineChart,
  Line,
  XAxis,
  YAxis,
  CartesianGrid,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  ResponsiveContainer,
  PieChart,
  Pie,
  Sector,
  Cell,
  BarChart,
  Bar
} from "recharts";
const data = [
  {
    name: "Page A",
    uv: 4000,
    pv: 2400,
    amt: 2400
  },
  {
    name: "Page B",
    uv: 3000,
    pv: 1398,
    amt: 2210
  },
  {
    name: "Page C",
    uv: 2000,
    pv: 8,
    amt: 2290
  },
  {
    name: "Page D",
    uv: 2780,
    pv: 3908,
    amt: 2000
  },
  {
    name: "Page E",
    uv: 18,
    pv: 4800,
    amt: 2181
  },
  {
    name: "Page F",
    uv: 2390,
    pv: 3800,
    amt: 2500
  },
  {
    name: "Page G",
    uv: 3490,
    pv: 4300,
    amt: 2100
  }
];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BarChart
      width={300}
      height={200}
      data={data}
      layout="vertical"
      margin={{
        top: 5,
        right: 30,
        left: 20,
        bottom: 5
      }}
    >
      <XAxis type="number" />
      <Bar dataKey="uv" fill="#8884d8" minPointSize={5} />
    </BarChart>
  );
}
```

It renders to this: [image: bar chart]

The bars are together I want to have a space between them

Here is the codesandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/bar-chart-with-min-height-forked-d3xktk?file=/src/App.tsx:0-1093

Answer (score 0):

you could add **barCategoryGap={14}** attribute and make the height a little bigger +50px

```html
<BarChart
      width={300}
      height={250}
      data={data}
      layout="vertical"
      margin={{
        top: 5,
        right: 30,
        left: 20,
        bottom: 5
      }}
      barCategoryGap={14}
    >
      <XAxis type="number" />
      <Bar dataKey="uv" fill="#8884d8" minPointSize={5} />
    </BarChart>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do it by setting `barSize` to `12`, which will create space between the bars in your BarChart. You can adjust the `barSize` value to control the amount of space between the bars to suit your visual preferences.

here is the updated code:

```
<BarChart
      width={300}
      height={200}
      data={data}
      layout="vertical"
      margin={{
        top: 5,
        right: 30,
        left: 20,
        bottom: 5
      }}
    >
      <XAxis type="number" />
      <Bar dataKey="uv" fill="#8884d8" minPointSize={5} barSize={12} /> {/* Adjust the barSize as needed */}
    </BarChart>
```